# Change Android AnalogClock Color

Tags: android-widget

I try to change the AnalogClock color.
I want it Black instead of White.

Anybody know how can I overide this widget theme.

Thanks a lot .

```
<AnalogClock
           android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
           android:layout_marginTop="500dp" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the images of the dial, hand_hour and hand_minute:

```
<AnalogClock
    android:id="@+id/analogClock1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    **android:dial="@drawable/my_dial_image"
    android:hand_hour="@drawable/my_hand_hour_image"
    android:hand_minute="@drawable/my_hand_minute_image"** />
```

Eduardo

connect-motion.com

Comment: Can we change programatically?